# How can I enable hot reload of one specific node_modules package in my react native project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler, code-push

I have a react native application [here](https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native).

I want to enable hot reloading for a specific project, this is how I installed it, within `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
+    "my-dependency": "file:../my-dependency"
  }
}
```

Then `yarn`

How can I enable hot reload of one specific node_modules package in my react native project?

Comment: wouldn't it be a lot easier to integrate that package into your `src`? just a thought.

Comment: This package comes from a monorepo with it's own app. We want to reuse that package in another app so moving the project in a different repo is not an option that solve that need.